# How would I create a custom image marker in version 3.0 of the Mapbox iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, mapbox

How would I create a custom image marker in version 3.0 of the Mapbox iOS SDK?

I am trying to create a mapView that shows a bunch of images as map annotations. These images are downloaded remotely using a UIImageView category.

I looked through the examples online, but the "Custom Image Marker" example found [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk-legacy/examples/marker-custom-image/) seems a little outdated.

An example of what I'd like to create is attached below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Mapbox's documentation isn't very well organized at the moment. The link you need for version 3.0 custom marker is [here.](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/marker-image/)

I've just started playing around with Mapbox and custom markers. I've used their provided Tower of Pisa images just to try it out. Those work fine but I've had trouble getting my own images to work. Let me know how you do.

Good luck!